# Cannot get request values Soap Request when tag has prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a client that sends me a soap request

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://com.test">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:Transfer>
<TransferRequest>


<transferDescription></transferDescription>
<ccy>XOF</ccy>

</TransferRequest>
</ns1:Transfer>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

below is my webmethod

```
[return: XmlElement(ElementName = "return")]
        [SoapDocumentMethod(Use = SoapBindingUse.Default)]

        public TransferResponse Transfer(TransferRequest TransferRequest)
        {


        }
    public class TransferResponse{

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    }


public class TransferRequest
    {
[XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.test")]
            public string transferDescription {get;set;}
[XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.test")]
        public string ccy{get;set;}
    }
```

When i remove the ns1 in `<ns1:Transfer>` to be `<Transfer>` i get the request values, but when i add it back like `<ns1:Transfer>` the object is null. How do i handle the request with the prefix, n1

Answer (score 0):

you should add the namespace so the deserializer will know how to parse your XML

> ```
> [XmlElement(Namespace="YOUR NAMESPACE")]
> ```

at the example you posted your xml namespace is:

> xmlns:ns1="http://com.test"

verify that your XML Schema is reachable by the code, and then the deserialization should work just fine.

you can read more about XML scheme and XML namespace [in here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please where should i add it?

Comment: Like i said, the request comes from a client, i just mocked it, to see why it wasnt getting to me, so i dont know who the namespace com.test is